# Find the equation of the tangent line at the point

Tags: calculus

I need to find the equation of the tangent line at the point $(3,1)$ for 
$$x\ln y + 2xy = 6.$$

Can you point out a way to start.

Comment: Sure we can. Start by taking the derivative of $y$ using [implicit differentiation](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html).

Comment: f(x,y)= x⋅ln(y)+2xy  gives me:  ln(y)+2y  Right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if you do it you will get:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y ln y + 2y^{2}}{-2xy-x}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = m_{t}$ which is the slope of the tangent line, now you have to evaluate the point$(3,1)$ in $m_{t}$ then you have that:

$m_{t} = \frac{(1) ln (1) + 2(1)^{2}}{-2(3)(1)-(3)} = \frac{-2}{9}$

then remember that with $y-y_{0} = m(x-x_{0})$ you can find the equation of any line

So the equation of the tangent line is

$y-1 = \frac{-2}{9}(x-3) $ or $ y = \frac{-2x}{9} + \frac{5}{3}$ and its done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Either

(1) use implicit differentiation to find $\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{(x,y)=(3,1)}$, or

(2) note that you can write $x$ as a function of $y$ and find the tangent line as a function of $y$.